# Use tsconfig.json for tsc with syntastic in vim

Tags: vim, typescript, syntastic

I want to use the `syntastic` plugin for `vim` to give me live error checking while I'm writing typescript files, using `tsc`. I already have `tsc` activated in `vim`. Any suggestions for how I could get `tsc` to use the closest parent's `tsconfig.json` file as configuration? I find that `tsc` doesn't do so by default, which makes `syntastic` configuration difficult. Thanks!

EDIT: The reason I think it's not using `tsconfig.json` is because options like the module resolution method doesn't seem to be working ("require" not defined), and it also isn't catching my definition files as defined in the `files` attribute in `tsconfig.json`.

My failed attempt to solve this:

```
let g:syntastic_typescript_checks=['tsc', 'tslint']

" typescript: find tsconfig.json
function! FindTypescriptRoot()
    return fnamemodify(findfile('tsconfig.json', './;'), ':h')
endfunction

let g:syntastic_typescript_tsc_args=['-p', FindTypescriptRoot()]
```

This results in Syntastic spitting out to me this error:

```
app.ts|| TS5042: Option 'project' cannot be mixed with source files on a command line.
```

This is probably because it's running a command like `tsc -p /path/to/project/ app.ts`, which is an illegal use of that flag... But I don't understand why my settings in `tsconfig.json` are being ignored by `syntastic` :(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Summary

Add `let g:syntastic_typescript_tsc_fname = ''` to `.vimrc`.

### Details

As [romainl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546861/romainl) mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34103059/95592), the ["Using tsconfig.json"](https://github.com/Microsoft/typescript/wiki/tsconfig.json#using-tsconfigjson) section of the Typescript wiki states:

> By invoking tsc with no input files, in which case the compiler searches for the `tsconfig.json` file starting in the current directory and continuing up the parent directory chain.

You can do this in [Vim](http://www.vim.org) using [Syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) by adding the following to your `.vimrc`, or `.vimrc.after` if you use [Janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus), as found in [LCD 047](https://github.com/lcd047)'s answer to your [Syntastic issue #1628](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues/1628):

```
let g:syntastic_typescript_tsc_fname = ''
```

Comment: Solved the issue perfectly for me. Should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This does work. However once set I no longer get the error markers on error. However if I do `Errors` I can see the tsc errors.

Answer (score 2):

[The wiki says:](https://github.com/Microsoft/typescript/wiki/tsconfig.json#using-tsconfigjson)

> ### Using tsconfig.json
>
> - By invoking `tsc` with no input files, in which case the compiler searches for the `tsconfig.json` file starting in the current directory and continuing up the parent directory chain.
> - By invoking `tsc` with no input files and a `-project` (or just `-p`) command line option that specifies the path of a directory containing a `tsconfig.json` file.
>
> When input files are specified on the command line, `tsconfig.json` files are ignored.

So, basically, you need to find a way to tell Syntastic to *not* pass the filename to `tsc`.

I'd suggest using their issue tracker from now on.